# Shorten waiting time VB program with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

What is the best way to limit the waiting times to open and close the connections? My server has a limit of 10 open connections.  The problem with opening and closing a connection every time, is that the user interface becomes very slow...

Quick breakdown of what I have so far:

- Program in VB.NET that will be used by +10 different clients
- Each client will have their own MySQL database with the relevant information
- VB connects to MySQL with the MySQL connector version 6.8.3
- Every single form (total of 15) needs information from the database to display correctly

Any tips that I should investigate?

Thanks guys!

Max

p.s. This might be a too-open or too-opinion based question, my excuses...

Comment: mysql has afairly quick connection protocol. there's essentially nothing you can do to "limit waiting times". generally speaking the queries you're running will take far longer than the it takes for the connection to be established.

Comment: .NET creates a connection pooling for connections. So if you creates a connection, use it and close it for every query, only the first connection should take longer time. All consecutive connection use the pool of connections. Are the conection string always the same?

Comment: Yes Eric, all the connection strings are the same. But that is good news, that for .Net i don't have to keep the same connection open the whole time.